# Why dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this) works but Object obj; dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(obj) doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing, oop

Please go through and help me understand why :

```
public Class Frame extends JFrame{

public void JbInit(){
JDialog dia = new JDialog();
dia.setSize(200,200);
dia.setLocationRelativeTo(this);// this will work fine while we are passing the current object.
dia.setVisibile(true);
NewFrame obj = new NewFrame();
obj.newDialog(this);
}
}

Class NewFrame{
public void newDialog(object obj){
    JDialog dia = new JDialog();
    dia.setSize(200,200);
    dia.setLocationRelativeTo(obj);
  dis.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This will not work , set Location method will take component as argument, so here it will ask to cast it as Component, after casting to component it is throwing class cast exception.

Comment: Try with `dia.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` to show the `Window` in the center of the screen.

Comment: What you want to achieve? What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method you're calling - `JComponent.setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)`  takes a `Component` parameter, not an `Object` parameter.

If you think about it, it wouldn't make sense otherwise: To `setLocationRelativeTo` something, you need to know what that something's location is. `Component` is structured to accommodate this, but arbitrary objects are not.

Would:

```
Double d = new Double(4.48);
dia.setLocationRelativeTo(d);
```

or

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(false);
dia.setLocationRelativeTo(b);
```

make sense?

**Addendum**: It sounds like you need to read up on [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

<s>This</s> The following is acceptable:

```
public Class Frame extends JFrame{
      ...
     dia.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
```

because `this` in this context refers to an instance of `Frame`, which extends `JFrame`, which extends `JComponent`. The following is unacceptable:

```
public void newDialog(Object obj){
    JDialog dia = new JDialog();
    dia.setSize(200,200);
    dia.setLocationRelativeTo(obj);
```

because `obj` is an instance of `Object`, which does not.

Comment: Thanks for ans but if we pass "this" to method setLocationRelativeTo it will take as object. Suppose we are passing "this" to method newDialog(Component obj), then also it won't accept this as component. "this" will remain treated as object only. Please check and provide clarification ?

Comment: `JFrame` is a compoenent.

Comment: @Braj where in my answer does that seem to be refuted?

Comment: What does it mean here *takes a Component parameter, not an Object parameter.* As per OP code the object is `JFrame`. Why the last sample code in your post is unacceptable?

Comment: @Braj It means that you can't pass an arbitrary `Object` into `JComponent.setLocationRelativeTo()`, it won't compile... The object is a `JFrame` in OP's first example here (which works), but in the second example (which doesn't) it's not - it's an `Object`.

Comment: @Braj Look again at OP's second example. There's not a `JFrame` in sight there... How is "the object a `JFrame`"?:

Comment: Look at the first example from where it is called and that is correct. `NewFrame obj = new NewFrame(); obj.newDialog(this);`

Comment: @Braj It doesn't matter where/how it's called, the `NewFrame` class itself won't compile with a reference to an `Object` in as a parameter to that method. Changing `public void newDialog(Object obj){}` to `public void newDialog(Component obj){}` would work fine.

Comment: Finally I got it. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Vishwas see my addendum for clarification. Ignore the rest of this comment trace

Comment: @drewmore suppose if we pass newFrame.newDialog(this); and we collect this parameter in public void newDialog(Frame obj); then dia.setLocationRelativeTo(obj); will it work ?

Comment: @Vishwas Yes, it sure will! Can you tell me why?